# "lein repl" on Heroku — rlwrap: Could not open master pty

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I have just deployed a version of my Clojure application to Heroku.

I cannot open lein repl using "heroku run":

```
$ heroku run lein repl
Running lein repl attached to terminal... up, run.6649
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=true
rlwrap: Could not open master pty: Exec format error
```

This has worked previously.